# Accessing Jenkins global property in Groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins, global-variables

At this moment I defined a environment variable called GLOBAL_VAR with the value 'test' under Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global Properties. I have a shell script when a project is being build containing

```
echo "The value of the global variable is ${GLOBAL_VAR}"
```

If executed, the result is what I expected:

```
The value of the global variable is test
```

Now my problem is that I want to access this variable in a Groovy script which is used to create a drop-down menu in the parameterized build properties of Jenkins. This drop-down menu contains values also used in the shell script(s) executed when a build is performed. So the drop down items should be created when someone clicks "Build with Parameters" in Jenkins itself e.g. **before any build is started**.

I don't want to change the shell script code and the drop-down Groovy script every time I want to change these values. Moreover, I want to use the same values in different build jobs which means I need to change them all every time I need to change a variable.

The Dynamic Choice Parameter creating the drop-down menu contains only the following Groovy expression to generate the choices:

```
 def list = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]
```

And I want to add the value of my GLOBAL_VAR to this list.

Does anyone know how to access the Jenkins environment variables in Groovy? Or does anyone know a different way to manage variables I want to use both within the Dynamic Choice Parameter (drop-down menu) and in the shell scripts executed when building?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of some working code:

```
import jenkins.model.*
nodes = Jenkins.instance.globalNodeProperties
nodes.getAll(hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class)
envVars = nodes[0].envVars
envVars['MY_GLOBAL_PROPERTY']
```

Sources of my solution:

https://gist.github.com/johnyzed/2af71090419af2b20c5a

http://pghalliday.com/jenkins/groovy/sonar/chef/configuration/management/2014/09/21/some-useful-jenkins-groovy-scripts.html

Note to the "hard core" moderator that deleted my previous answer: I have spent quite a few hours searching on the Internet before finding the right solution, you shouldn't delete posts without knowing what is it really talking about.  I find such behavior rather discouraging :(

Comment: Worked perfectly. It should be the accepted answer to help people like me in future.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me as well. Thank you! +1 for this being an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

in "Execute Groovy script" you can access global (and build) variables by:

```
def env = System.getenv()
println(env['GLOBAL_VAR'])
```

Comment: The script which helps creating the drop down list is executed in Jenkins itself when I open the Build with Parameters page. I guess this might be the problem since I get an empty variable when doing what you suggest. `tmplist << env['GLOBAL_STRING_BACKUP']`

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
import jenkins.model.*
instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
globalNodeProperties = instance.getGlobalNodeProperties()
envVarsNodePropertyList = globalNodeProperties.getAll(hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class)

newEnvVarsNodeProperty = null
envVars = null

if ( envVarsNodePropertyList == null || envVarsNodePropertyList.size() == 0 ) {
  newEnvVarsNodeProperty = new hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty();
  globalNodeProperties.add(newEnvVarsNodeProperty)
  envVars = newEnvVarsNodeProperty.getEnvVars()
} else {
  envVars = envVarsNodePropertyList.get(0).getEnvVars()

}

envVars.put("FOO", "foo")
instance.save()
```

The solution was found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/KgCGuDmED1Q)

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how to access the Jenkins environment variables in
>   groovy?

I can provide an example from a Jenkins job we use.  The job is **parameterized** and provides the user with the ability to set many values, one of which is "InstallVersion" (default value is -1).  Additionally, we set up an environment variable called "JENKINS_TRUNK_LABEL".  I won't go into specifics about this job, but, here's how we refer to "JENKINS_TRUNK_LABEL" within a Groovy script.

```
if (InstallVersion == "-1")
{
  InstallVersion = "$JENKINS_TRUNK_LABEL"
}
```

Comment: As soon as I add test = "$GLOBAL_VAR" to my Groovy script, it stops working. I added some details to my question for more information.

Comment: Do you have additional information about how you have set up the JENKINS_TRUNK_LABEL variable, possible imports in the Groovy script and/or possible plugins you have used?

Comment: The ability to use the environment variable in that manner is due to the type of Groovy plugin.  We currently have three installed, but, I believe that it's the Groovy Label Assignment plugin that's being used.  My understanding is that the environment variable access mechanism is dependent upon the context of when you want to access it.  For example, pre-build, post-build, etc.  That's why we use three different plugins.

Comment: I agree that the problem indeed has something to do with the moment at which you want to access the variable(s). In your case you access them pre-build, but after the person has clicked the build button, or am I wrong? I need the script to run after the user clicks on 'Build with Parameters' but before they are presented the page; the options for the parameters have to be loaded by then.