# How to get Jenkins node configurations from groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, configuration, jenkins-agent

I would like to use a groovy script in a job to read all the node configurations as viewed in the Node configuration in the Jenkins GUI. I know that it is possible to use the REST API to fetch node configurations, but I would like to know how to do this using the available library methods, e.g. from a system Groovy script.

I envision something like this pseudo-code to print the Host as it is configured in the "Launch method" setting, if launch method is set to SSH:

```
jenkins.getNodes().each { node ->
    println(node.getLaunchMethod().getHost())
}
```

The answers to [Accessing Jenkins global property in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242062/accessing-jenkins-global-property-in-groovy) seems possibly to be relevant?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not very clear. You can take a look at the [javadoc for the library methods](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Node.html). I don't see `getLaunchMethod()`, but to get the hostnames you can do `jenkins.nodes().each { node -> println(node.computer.hostName) }` (assuming all Nodes are [Slave](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Slave.html)s).

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. Is was just pseudo-code for retrieving some value from the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use dedicated tool for such tasks which is JenkinsCli in my opinion. Just navigate to this URL in your Jenkins instance:
`http://your_jenkins_instance:8080/cli/command/get-node`
You can get XML describing your node when you run CLI with this option, so then you can parse it in a way you need.

To wrap this somehow into the pipeline I would suggest to create such a steps:

- get CLI to your workspace:
  `sh "curl -O http://localhost:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar"`
- run CLI in you workspace:
  `sh 'java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ -auth user:pass -webSocket get-node Test1'`

of course user:pass should be sourced from Jenkins secrets.
Anyway, I would discourage hacking with libraries (making approvals to allow specific code compromising security) and would use this tool instead, configuring specific user for this purpose and making it accessible via secrets.